# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found working in Eclipse, but not in IntelliJ

Tags: java, apache-tomee

I am working on a school project. It is a Java EE web app with JPA and EJB running on a TomEE server. My problem occurs when I try to retrieve a list of phone numbers from my database.

Project structure: [Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEbcg.png) [Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRMXi.png) [Facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5rg.png)

Server Setup:

- TomEE 8.5.50 (Webprofile 7.1.2)
- EclipseLink 2.7.4.jar
- Postgresql 42.2.8.jar

I only get this error in IntelliJ (Ultimate), not in Eclipse. I also testing making the exact same query to the DB that causes the error via DBeaver and it worked flawlessly.

Anyone got a tip as to where my problem might be?

The Entity Access Object:

```
package eao;

import entities.BrukerEntity;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class BrukerEAO {

    @PersistenceContext(name="expo2020PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<BrukerEntity> hentBrukerliste() {
        return em.createQuery("select b from BrukerEntity b", BrukerEntity.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="expo2020PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <jta-data-source>javax.sql.DataSource</jta-data-source>

        <class>entities.AvstemningEntity</class>
        <class>entities.BrukerEntity</class>
        <class>entities.StandEntity</class>
        <class>entities.StemmeEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://data1.hib.no:5433/dat109_v20_prosjekt06"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="<REDACTED>"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="<REDACTED>"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error log:

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DAT109_V20_PROSJEKT06
Error Code: -5501
Call: SELECT mobilnummer FROM dat109_v20_prosjekt06.expo2020.bruker
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=BrukerEntity sql="SELECT mobilnummer FROM dat109_v20_prosjekt06.expo2020.bruker")
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:447)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:351)
    eao.BrukerEAO$$LocalBeanProxy.hentBrukerliste(eao/BrukerEAO.java)
    servlets.StemmeServlet.doGet(StemmeServlet.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)

Root Cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DAT109_V20_PROSJEKT06
Error Code: -5501
Call: SELECT mobilnummer FROM dat109_v20_prosjekt06.expo2020.bruker
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=BrukerEntity sql="SELECT mobilnummer FROM dat109_v20_prosjekt06.expo2020.bruker")
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:391)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:264)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    eao.BrukerEAO.hentBrukerliste(BrukerEAO.java:17)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
    eao.BrukerEAO$$LocalBeanProxy.hentBrukerliste(eao/BrukerEAO.java)
    servlets.StemmeServlet.doGet(StemmeServlet.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)

Root Cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DAT109_V20_PROSJEKT06
Error Code: -5501
Call: SELECT mobilnummer FROM dat109_v20_prosjekt06.expo2020.bruker
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=BrukerEntity sql="SELECT mobilnummer FROM dat109_v20_prosjekt06.expo2020.bruker")
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:342)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:691)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2096)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:603)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:275)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:261)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:332)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:728)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2773)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2726)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:584)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1224)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:914)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1183)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1271)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2981)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1895)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1877)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1842)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:262)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    eao.BrukerEAO.hentBrukerliste(BrukerEAO.java:17)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
    eao.BrukerEAO$$LocalBeanProxy.hentBrukerliste(eao/BrukerEAO.java)
    servlets.StemmeServlet.doGet(StemmeServlet.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)

Root Cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DAT109_V20_PROSJEKT06
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:75)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1595)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1544)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:806)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:628)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2096)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:603)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:275)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:261)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:332)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:728)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2773)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2726)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:584)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1224)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:914)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1183)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1271)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2981)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1895)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1877)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1842)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:262)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    eao.BrukerEAO.hentBrukerliste(BrukerEAO.java:17)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
    eao.BrukerEAO$$LocalBeanProxy.hentBrukerliste(eao/BrukerEAO.java)
    servlets.StemmeServlet.doGet(StemmeServlet.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)

Root Cause

org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DAT109_V20_PROSJEKT06
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.checkValidCatalogName(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:75)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1595)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1544)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:806)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:628)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2096)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:603)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:275)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:261)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:332)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:728)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2773)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2726)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:584)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1224)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:914)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1183)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1271)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2981)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1895)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1877)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1842)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:262)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    eao.BrukerEAO.hentBrukerliste(BrukerEAO.java:17)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
    eao.BrukerEAO$$LocalBeanProxy.hentBrukerliste(eao/BrukerEAO.java)
    servlets.StemmeServlet.doGet(StemmeServlet.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
```

Comment: Is this a maven project?

Comment: It is not a maven project

Comment: So, Are you using Intellij community or Ultimate?

Comment: Ultimate, will edit the post

Comment: Could you show us the structure of your project? because a non-maven project structure could differ from and IDE to another.

Comment: I have edited the post now with images of the proj structure.